# Nginx conf setup for one install multiple websites

Tags: magento2, nginx

I was able to install MG 2 on `nginx` and everything is running without issue. But, I am unsure as to how to setup up multiple websites under one install.

The various walkthroughs and brief examples are seem to talk about multiple subdomain language stores under Magento. Is there a complete guide for setting up multiple websites on nginx (*.conf, etc/hosts, index.php edits / changes )

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the *To create multiple virtual hosts (customize per website)* in this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-site/ms_nginx.html#ms-nginx-vhosts

Specifically take a look at the usage of `$MAGE_RUN_TYPE` and `$MAGE_RUN_CODE`. You use those to associate a *sever block* or *vhost* with a specific magento store. Those values are passed along in the request and used by magento to determine which store or website the user should be forwarded to.

`$MAGE_RUN_TYPE` should be either `store` or `website` depending on which scope you want to use. `$MAGE_RUN_CODE` will be the store code or website code (depending on what you set for `$MAGE_RUN_TYPE`) of the store you want to use.

You don't have to use subdomains, you can use any domain you'd like (granted you have access to said domain).